# expand event for content added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display some collapsibles with data in my webpage and execute a function each time they are opened.

Now I can display them. I get them by an ajax call in a pageshow in my home page. Then I set in the html() of the content div in the second page (where they go)

They seem like this:

```
<div id='off_id_offer' class='offer_send_obs' onclick='offer_send_obs();' data-role='collapsible'>
   <h3><font size='4' face='verdana'>titulo</font></h3>
   <table border='0' style='width:100%;'>
      <tr>
         <td align='center'>
            fechas
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align='center' style='width:50%;'>
            <img style='width:70%;' src=imagen />
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            texto
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<br>
```

I tried adding an onclick function in this code and also creating a class to bind the function.

But when I click the collapsible in my webpage, nothing happens, nothing is launched.

This is my code for functions in javascript page:

```
function offer_send_obs(){
  console.log("function exec");
}

$('.offer_send_obs').on('click', '.offer_send_obs', function(){
  console.log("click exec");
});
```

I am using jquery 1.10.2 and jquery mobile 1.4.3

Comment: You're going the right way by using `delegation`. The solution is to find a selector that returns elements that will be there already. ie: `$('body').on('click', '.offer_send_obs'`

Comment: Or you can attach the `event handler` in the exactly moment you're adding the elements dynamically.

Comment: I don't get you about the event handler, can you give me an example?

Comment: The `event handling` is what I'm talking about on the piece of code posted on my first comment.

Comment: I just tried and it doesn't work. Nothing happens

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.offer_send_obs', function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});

Comment: That code should work. Have you made sure that the class exists? Try removing other code which may be interfering.

Comment: I set the class just in my div. Which I pass as text in a json file.